# Definition of howManyIntegers(n) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I implement this task?

Write a definition of `howManyIntegers(n)`,
which will return how many integers in the range `[1,n]` consist only of digits `{0, 2, 7, 9}`.

For example:

"in range(1, 10) there are 3 numbers -> 2,7,9"

"in range(1, 28) there are 6 numbers -> 2,7,9,20,22,27"

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Since you are new, you should check out [ask] and the [help]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga His question is totally clear. For a moment instead of saying that directly, look at the question a little because it's totally clear, understandable and intelligible.

Comment: @xdrps the specification is clear. The *issue* the OP is encountering is not. This isn't a code-writing service, where we just do people's assignments for them

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga StackOverflow's purpose, as I understand it, is to help people. To transmit knowledge that others may not have. And even if the person asks questions which are not necessarily very hard questions, there is no problem in helping them. If you had been in the same problem you probably wouldn't have wanted us to answer you like this. Then why do you do it to others?

Comment: The purpose of stack overflow isn't to do people's homework for them. By all means, ask questions related to your homework, although, I would [take a look this first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have many answers!

**Answer 1:**

If you want to do it the easy way, you can do:

```py
def howManyIntegers(n):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1,n):
        b = True
        for c in str(i):
            b &= c in "0279"
        t += b
    return t
```

What that basically does:
Initialize a variable t as 0.

For loop in 1,n range.

Initialize a variable b (for boolean) as True

If every char in str(i) is in "0279" => b will be True

If b is True: t+=1

**Answer 2:**

```py
def howManyIntegers(n: int):
    t: int = 0
    for i in range(1,n):
        t += "".join(filter(lambda x: x if x in "0279" else "", str(i))) == str(i)
    return t
```

In this answer, I tried to put some extra features like explicitly typing and filter function.

What `"".join(filter(lambda x: x if x in "0279" else "", str(i))) == str(i)` basically does: it only keeps char on i which are in "0279" and compare this string to str(i). <=> if they are equals, str(i) is only composed of 0, 2, 7 and 9.

**Answer 3**

Last but not least!

If you want to do it in a *golfy* style, you can do something like:

```py
def howManyIntegers(n):return sum("".join(filter(lambda x:["",x][x in"0279"],str(i)))==str(i)for i in range(1,n))
```

If you have questions, don't hesitate! :)

Comment: @Grzegorz You're Welcome!
Don't hesitate to mark this answer as correct if it is a correct answer! :)

Comment: Done. One more time, thanks :)